# How to get thumbnail view for Photoshop (psd) in Windows 7 64 bit OS?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, thumbnails, psd

How to get thumbnail view for Photoshop (.psd) in Windows 7 64 bit OS?

Answer (score 5):

Let me recommend you [SageThumbs](http://code.google.com/p/sagethumbs/):

[image]

> SageThumbs is a Windows shell extension that provides thumbnail preview for more than 160 image formats. Although Windows Explorer can already display thumbnails, it only supports a handful of formats. With SageThumbs, you can view thumbnails for many camera specific RAW files, Photoshop images and many other formats. In addition, it provides an (optional) thumbnail in the context menu as well as image conversion features and enhance tooltips in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Just checked it's not working well. In the same folder I have many PSD files but it's only showing thumbnail for 2-3

Comment: @metalgearsolid Sage Thumbs will only show thumbnails for files under a certain size You can configure that size to be larger using the right-click context menu, options. I had the same problem with some PSD files not showing thumbnails until I worked out the filesize thing.

Answer (score 4):

I found [Pictus](http://poppeman.se/pictus) on another forum and it's super easy, free, and open source. From its description:

> - Supports BMP, GIF, JPG, PCX, PNG, PSD (Adobe Photoshop), PSP (Corel Paint Shop Pro), TGA, TIFF, WBMP and XYZ
> - Helps Windows Explorer show thumbnails for those formats.

Install it and seconds later you will be very happy. I use it on Windows 7.

Comment: I understand, own experience, not just forum hearsay? Do you use Win7 x86 or Win7 x64? (kinda important in this context...) Best!

Comment: Thanks for this! It worked Great!!

Answer (score 3):

I've had good results with [FastPictureViewer Codec Pack](http://www.fastpictureviewer.com/codecs/). This is commerical software but the price is low.

Comment: I can second that! FastPictureViewer works great. I am using it under Win7 x64 (ultimate), on Canon 7D and 5D (mk iii) jpeg and more importantly raw (CR2) images and PSDs. (I didn't bother to intall all the other previews/thumbnailers. Only Canon Raw and PSD).

Answer (score 2):

I tried these free versions as psicon.dll and psdcodec.dll, they did not work for Windows 7 64bit, even with the suggested fixes found on the Internet.

Finally, I purchased the codec pack from FastPictureViewer.com (link is in the answer above). For me it cost $14.95. The site is registered with Microsoft and this codec pack provides thumbnail view of PhotoShop ".psd" extension as well as support for many other image formats not normally supported in the Windows 7 OS. Apparently 48 format extensions. That is pretty good.

I installed this codec pack, works great. This codec pack provides support for Windows Photo Viewer to display the ".psd" extension , so I image that the remaining 47 more extensions will also display in Windows Photo Viewer. In fact, read the webpage at the codec site as it offers a lot more than just thumbnail viewing in Explorer.

My payment went through PayPal, so security of my payment was assured.

I used CCleaner (free windows file cleaner) and Comodo System Cleaner to remove the faulty registry entries caused by the free codec versions.

Sometimes doing it free is not always the best course to take and for what little it cost, Fast Picture Viewer provided the better option without headaches and endless Google searches.

Lastly, this is not a sponsored post for Fast Picture Viewer, nor am I affiliated with the site or its company. I thought I would confirm to viewers that this codec pack is a good one worth the money.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a light weight thumbnail viewer then I agree with the user **TIm** above recommendation of [Pictus](https://poppeman.se/pictus/) - it works out of the box even on my Windows 8.1 Professional notebook and took seconds to install.

I am amazed that Adobe have not included anything in their products to allow previewing of PSD files (and other formats) this is a basic requirement for any graphics program and you would think they would have realised this after so many years!

Answer (score 0):

Sage Thumbs still works even with 2016 Photoshop CC.

The catch is (as one commenter pointed out) you need to change the file size limit if you're working with files above the default.

[image]

Photoshop saves previews (if enabled), so I don't see why not to check `Prefer image file embedded thumbnails` and hope this speeds it up regardless of filesize - but I'm unable to confirm for sure.

[image]